# LFS 7.2 glibc-2.16.0 make error

Tags: makefile, ld, glibc, linux-from-scratch, libgcc

I'm building an LFS system ( refering to LFS 7.2 )

I got this make error while building glibc-2.16.0:

```
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-lfs-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../i686-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.16.0/iconv'
make[1]: *** [iconv/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.16.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
lfs:/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build$
```

I located the libgcc_s file in three different places:

```
/usr/lib/libgcc_s-4.7.0-20120507.so.1
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.0/libgcc_s.so
```

I tried overiding the LDFLAGS variable but no success.
Can any one please help me with this problem. Or am I missing something? I don't know.
Please help guys,

My host system is Fedora 17.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories.  `LDFLAGS` would contain options to pass to the linker.

The likely problem is that you don't have `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.0` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  The other two libraries mentioned in `/usr/lib/` shall not be picked unless you have a symlink `libgcc_s.so` in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH that points to one of those.